# Elixir Coin Change

Tags: elixir

i need help to resolve the problem  coin change on elixir, and i don't know the problem please help me i'm new on elixir  i confuse in the sintax of elixir

```
defmodule MejorCambio do

    def darcambio() do
      precio = mensajeprecio()
      pago = mensajepago()
      cuerpo_mensaje_precio(pago, precio)

    end

  def mensajeprecio() do
    IO.gets "Insert  number 1 "
  end

  def mensajepago() do
    IO.gets "Insert number 2 "
  end
  def cuerpo_mensaje_precio(pago, precio) do
  abono = String.to_integer(pago |> String.trim_trailing)
  adeudo = String.to_integer(precio |> String.trim_trailing)
  cambio = abono - adeudo

  Enum.reduce([10, 5, 2, 1], 0 , fn divisa, acc ->

  repeat =  div(cambio, divisa)
  acc =  rem(cambio, divisa)

  IO.puts(repeat)
  IO.puts("###########")
  IO.puts(acc)
  IO.puts("########")

  end)

  end

end
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the issue you are having? Are you getting any errors? Is it just not working correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
defmodule MejorCambio do

    def darcambio(abono, adeudo) do
      td = abono - adeudo
      IO.inspect("Tu cambio es de #{td}")

      Enum.reduce([200,100,50,20,10, 5, 2, 1], %{abono: abono, adeudo: adeudo} , fn divisa, acc ->

        cambio = acc.abono - acc.adeudo

          repeat =  div(cambio, divisa)

          acc2 =  rem(cambio, divisa)

      %{deno: divisa , val: repeat} |> IO.inspect()

          %{acc | adeudo: acc2 * -1, abono: 0 }

      end)|> IO.inspect()


      end


    end
```